# fighting a parking ticket in NJ

Tags: police, traffic, new-jersey, parking

I received a parking ticket for overnight parking on a public street in NJ.  The municipality apparently has an ordnance against overnight parking but there was no signage on the roads.  I believe NJ requires both signage AND the restriction and appear in the duly passed list of municipal ordinances-- but I can’t find that in writing anywhere.  Does anyone know where I can find the NJ state requirement of signage?  thanks

Comment: It is almost never worth the time and money involved to fight a parking ticket.